# In python how to work with selected Outlook email

Tags: python, outlook, ms-office

I have a question that I need to do something automatically using the python. Now I want to write a script to help me point the email I select.

Now, the next action is that I want to work on selected email currently in the all_mail_box. not sure how to write.

My code is as follows:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
adrLi = outlook.AddressLists.Item("全域通訊清單")
contacts = adrLi.AddressEntries

nameAliasDict = {}
for i in contacts:
  name = i.Name
  alias = i.Address.split("=")[-1]
  #department = i.Department  <-- I want to get the department which is in the contact
  nameAliasDict[alias, department] = name
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can work with **[ActiveExplorer() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.activeexplorer?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__Application_ActiveExplorer)** of Outlook Application.*

*Example*

```
import win32com.client
olApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

if olApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0:
    Msg = olApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    print("Subject: " + Msg.Subject)
else:
    print("Error Nothing selected.")
```